# Two account authentication in Windows 10 PC for log in access?

Tags: windows, authentication

I have been trying to implement a security design common in safety boxes where two keys are required to unlock the box.

In my case, I want to unlock a USER in windows 10 only and only if two different passwords are entered. This is to basically to create a check on the other user who has been using the PC disproportionately.

Is there an application already available to implement this?

Comment: Do you mean two factor authentication ?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible?

Comment: Tried googling for 2fa and w10 ? But I don't think they will support two _passwords_.https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/06/01/goodbye-passwords.aspx?m=1